# Can I put a clothesline between two rafters?

Tags: wood, roof

If I attach a rope to two distant rafters and use it as clothesline, would this put excess pressure on the rafters?
This is a roof over a deck. I thought it could be handy on a rainy day, but not sure if there is anything I need to consider first.

Comment: Are they actually rafters (directly fastened to the roof deck), or are they components in a truss?

Comment: Yes, these are rafters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would depend on whose clothes you're hanging, Paul Bunyan's or King Kong's??

No, that type of load on the rafters would not pose a problem. You could screw two eye bolts into the bottom of the rafters and tie your clothesline to them or put hooks on he end of the clothesline and then hook it through the eye bolts for easy removal.

Comment: How much do Paul Bunyan's clothes weigh?  How far off the floor are the rafters?   I mean if his pants are halfway on the floor what is the use of the clothesline?

Comment: @DMoore  The top half gets dry.. :-)

Comment: Wait does King Kong ever wear clothes?   This seems like a trick answer.

Comment: @DMoore Only in New York.....   (you know we're not supposed to joke around on this site... right?? )

Answer (score 3):

That sounds safe to me. clothes-line rope is unlikely to be strong enough to damage the rafters.

Comment: Even heavy lifting rope uses as a clothesline wouldn't cause any issues. Unless you're hanging an engine block from it waiting for the oil to drain out...